# html navigation bar doesn't detect whether it's open or not

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, navigationbar

The navigation bar for my website clearly has a logical error. I know this because the browser (I'm using chrome) is not detecting any other errors (e.g. syntax errors) and because it works partially.

The problem with my navigation bar is that it can't detect if it is open or not. So, the it is possible for the menu button to show a close button even though the menu is already closed (and vice versa).

The way my navigation bar works is by changing its shape every time it's clicked (menu icon changes for every click rather than when the menu opens).

You can see this problem in action when resizing the window/screen and opening the menu without closing it.

I'm trying to make my navigation bar 'responsive' by changing its design according to the screen size (large screens have navigation on the side, small screens have navigation at the top); this is when my problem started to occur.

I couldn't solve this because I am a beginner in javascript and jQuery, so, is there another approach that is more efficient and works better?

Thanks

Edit: You can't see the effect unless you copy my code, save it and open it via an external browser (@media won't work if you run the snippet)

Here is the code:

```js
function menuTransform(x) {
 var y = document.getElementById("navbar");
 var z = $(window).width();
 x.classList.toggle("change");
 if (z > 500) {
  $('nav li:not(.menu)').show();
  $('nav hr').show();
  if (y.style.width === "300px") {
   y.style.transition = "ease 0.5s";
   $('nav li a span').addClass('link');
   $('nav li a span').removeClass('opened');
   y.style.width = "80px";
  }
  
  else {
   y.style.transition = "ease 0.5s";
   $('nav li a span').removeClass('link');
   $('nav li a span').addClass('opened');
   y.style.width = "300px";
  }
 }
 
 if (z <= 500) {
  $('nav li:not(.menu)').hide();
  $('nav hr').hide();
  if (y.style.height === "100%") {
   y.style.height = "80px";
   y.style.width = "100%";
   y.style.transition = "ease 0.5s";
   $('nav li a span').addClass('link');
   $('nav li:not(.menu)').hide();
   $('nav hr').hide();
  }
  
  else {
   y.style.height = "100%";
   y.style.width = "100%";
   y.style.transition = "ease 0.5s";
   $('nav li a span').removeClass('link');
   $('nav li:not(.menu)').show();
   $('nav hr').show();
  }
 }
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
 z-index: 10;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(13,13,13));
 width: 80px;
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 box-shadow: 5px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 overflow: auto;
}

nav li {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

nav li a {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.link {
 display: none;
}

.opened {
 padding: 10px;
 padding-top: 11px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background: rgb(42,42,42);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.menu {
 padding-top: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.hamMenu {
 padding-top: -6px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 background: white;
 width: 36px;
 height: 5px;
 margin: 6px 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.change .bar1 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 7px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 7px);
}

.change .bar2 {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.change .bar3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<nav id="navbar">
 <li class="menu">
  <div class="hamMenu" onclick="menuTransform(this)">
   <div class="bar1"></div>
   <div class="bar2"></div>
   <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
 </li>
    
 <li><a class="active" href="home.html"><i class="material-icons">home</i><span class="link">Home</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="Videos.html"><i class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i><span class="link">Videos</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#seminars"><i class="material-icons">tv</i><span class="link">Seminars</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#seminars"><i class="material-icons">school</i><span class="link">Personal Tuition</span></a></li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect. `li` should live inside `ol` or `ul`. That's probably not causing the problem. I'd need to inspect it. But, the thing is: you're not listening to the window resize anywhere in your code and I don't actually see that you are calling `menuTransform` function. There are a few approaches. If you want, it can be done with JS, but this is simple enough for CSS as well (with maybe 2-3 lines of JS). What would be your preferred approach?

Comment: A CSS approach would be preferred as it is supported by more browsers, but if javascript is more efficient I would use JS. Thanks for the advice, I will start using <ul>/<ol> instead of just <nav>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ham menu has no width or height. You have it set like this:

```
.hamMenu {
    padding-top: -6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

So, you're trying to click on it on the page, but you're not clicking on it because it has no size, even though it has elements inside of it that have size.

A good way to test this is to give the element an outline, which will show you its size:

```
.hamMenu {
    padding-top: -6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 1px solid;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but eventually it should be something like this:

```
.hamMenu {
    padding-top: -6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 36px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my code must be confusing, I will edit it so its more understandable. hamMenu is just the menu icon, there is not problem with it (css problems). But thanks for the help though

Comment: The navigation bar works but I am asking if there is a way to make it more efficient and if there is a way to make it work seamlessly by changing its size (goes at the top rather than the bottom) if the window size changes (using media queries or javascript).

Sorry if you got didn't understand, i'm not good at explaining things